# sum column from all rows in the result not working

Tags: mysql

I am going to sum a column in the result but it is not working correctly with me, my SQL query is:

```
SELECT
    journal.id,
    journal.date,
    transactions.amount,
    transactions.journal,
    transactions.type
FROM `journal`
INNER JOIN `transactions`
    ON journal.id = transactions.journal AND
       transactions.type = 0
WHERE
    journal.date <= '2017-10-09'
GROUP BY
    journal.id AND ISNULL(@marker := IF(journal.id = ".$item->id.", 1, NULL))
```

It is returning an array:

```
array:2 [
  0 => {#2557
    +"id": 93
    +"date": "2017-10-05"
    +"amount": -138000.0
    +"journal": 93
    +"type": "0"
  }
  1 => {#1350
    +"id": 105
    +"date": "2017-10-05"
    +"amount": -126.0
    +"journal": 105
    +"type": "0"
  }
]
```

and I would like to get a single result instead that has the sum of `amount` column in the rows, I tried to add `SUM('transactions.amount')` after the first SELECT, but it didn't get the result I want.

I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show sample data along with the output you expect.  As it stand now, it is pointless for you to even use `GROUP BY`, because you are not selecting any aggregate values.

Comment: Hey Tim, nice to meet you again. What kind of data I should provide exactly? My point is to sum the output result `amount` column of all returned rows in a new row or a single column, or to have it in any other way.

Comment: Sample input data.  Let's get the query working first, then worry about other things.